# Callback on AJAX request doesn't fire

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've a MVC action method and I want to return a list of element in JSON format, to a callback function of a AJAX request. But when a send the response of a action method with a array of element on JSON, the callback function doesn't fire.

This is an implementation of my action method :

```
    public JsonResult ListAnexos(string idRelatorio)
    {

       EasyClinicEntities entities = new EasyClinicEntities();

        IQueryable<EasywebAnexos> _list = from EasywebAnexos in entities.EasywebAnexos
                                              where EasywebAnexos.IdRelatorios == idRelatorio
                                              select EasywebAnexos;


            return Json(new { List = _list.ToList().ToArray() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

my AJAX request code :

```
function makeRefreshAnexos(relatorio) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Anexos/ListAnexos?idRelatorio="+relatorio,
        success: function (jsonObject) {

          alert(jsonObjct);

        }
    });
}
```

When I try to send a JSON object like the code above, the callback function works fine.

```
public JsonResult ListAnexos(string idRelatorio){
     return Json(new {id="just for test"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I use the .net framework 4.0 and MVC 2.

Comment: You're probably getting an error.  Check Firebug.

Comment: Did you observe in Fiddler/Firebug on what the Http Request passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into an issue when using EF created classes as JSON return classes and the error is not immediately apparent. If the class has any navigation properties, The JSON serializer will fail due to a serialization loop. The easy way to fix this is to give your navigation properties internal getter accessors in the EF designer.

If you want an easy way to retrieve the error in Javascript code you can use this for quick and easy debugging:

```
function makeRefreshAnexos(relatorio) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Anexos/ListAnexos?idRelatorio="+relatorio,
    success: function (jsonObject) {
      alert(jsonObjct); 
   }, error: function(errorData){
      alert(errorData);
   }    
});}
```